# HighCharts moves screen position on load

Tags: highcharts

I have four HighCharts on a page, stacked vertically. In each of these charts I have buttons that change the data range and re-load the chart.

This works fine for the top two, but when the chart re-loads on the bottom two it moves the screen up the page, always to the same point.

With some testing I found that it doesn't matter what order the charts are in, and also if you click the button on the top form and scroll down the page, it moves the page back up to the same position.

It's like HighCharts has a lower limit on where the page an be and always moves it back to this position when a chart is loaded.

I can't find any settings within HighCharts or anything on Google that will sort this.

I thank you all in advance for your help

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because chart container height for a moment gets smaller on chart reload. You can fix this by setting fixed container height.